# SDL_Event, queue filling too quickly

Tags: c, events, queue, sdl

I'm using SDL2 to make an app, I developped it under Windows, everything worked well, then I wanted to compile it under Linux.

I noticed a big lag (few secs) between when I do an event and when the event was treated by my program. After some investigations, I found that the mouse motion is filling the queue of the sdl events way more quickly than on windows, and then my program has to consider every events encountered after each call of SDL_pollEvent.

So is there a way to limit the size of the queue, or ignoring some mouse motion events, or do you have any clean solution to give me ?

Comment: please *answer* your question, then accept your answer.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm not used to the site

Answer (score 0):

Alright I solved my problem by the following way, I post it so maybe it can help somebody else :

```
void reduce_queue(){
  static SDL_Event ev[MAX_EVENT_QUEUE + 1];
  static int i;
  static count;

  for(i = 0; i < MAX_EVENT_QUEUE && SDL_PollEvent(&ev[i]); i++);

  count = i;

  while(SDL_PollEvent(&ev[MAX_EVENT_QUEUE]));

  for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
    SDL_PushEvent(&ev[i]);
  }
}
```

And you call this function before every call to SDL_PollEvent or SDL_WaitEvent.

Comment: btw, why are you using `static` for that `i` there (or the event queue).

Comment: The function is called every frame (~30ms), so I said myself it was too expensive to create everytime new variables (SDL_Event is a quite big structure), maybe it is not a good choice I don't know

Comment: @Vito it isn't how automatic memory allocation works. That's beside the point that initial problem sounds strange as even thousands of events per frame is not a big deal, much more like handling of these events is clunky.

Comment: Let's take an example : if there is 100 events in the queue, because only 1 event is handled per frame, and because a frame is rendered every 30 ms, it will take 3sec to unload all the queue, considering between those 3 sec, you don't add other event on. So this solution works, I assume it's not the best one though. I had another idea afterall, it was to unload the queue every frame, considering every events, but it implies to modify the structure of the program.

Comment: "only 1 event is handled per frame" this is ridiculous and this is exactly a problem you need to address, not mitigate it via dropping events.